# Getting error the project is is connected not to Subversive provider but to another one: 'org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature'

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, locks

Using Eclipse Kepler release 2. 
Some projects are connected to Subversive and some are connected to subclipse.
Getting the error:

> ... is connected not to Subversive provider but to another one: 'org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature'.

Also the Subversive projects properties/team ... does not show the 'scan locks' option.
So have to manually drill down the project path to finds locked files and may miss checking in some files.

Can't upgrade all the subversive projects to subclipse for historical reasons.

My question is if I am missing a config change or fix that can enable the view showing 'scan locks' in the subversion/Team/ tab for the Subversive project?

Comment: Closing this issue. Solution is to delete the project from Eclipse and import it in again.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the project from Eclipse and reimporting it sometimes helps.
I currently have a case where this does not work and guess its related to the SVN Team provider setup.